# Rails 4 Runtime error in controller: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, circular-dependency, controllers

Let me know if I left anything out. I can't figure out why my views/references/ folder isn't accessible. neither `new.html.erb` nor `index.html.erb` is available. When I go to `localhost:3000/references` my error is:

```
RuntimeError in ReferencesController#index
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ReferencesController
```

I believe this is setup, and It shouldn't be a Rails issue because my other controllers are working fine.

My routes file has `resources :references` in it, my rake routes produces:

```
references GET    /references(.:format)          references#index
           POST   /references(.:format)          references#create
new_reference GET    /references/new(.:format)      references#new
edit_reference GET    /references/:id/edit(.:format) references#edit
reference GET    /references/:id(.:format)      references#show
           PATCH  /references/:id(.:format)      references#update
           PUT    /references/:id(.:format)      references#update
           DELETE /references/:id(.:format)      references#destroy
```

So I try to get to my index page by this which should be the correct path.

```
<%= link_to 'References', references_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %>
```

My model:

```
class Reference < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My controller:

```
class ReferencesControllers < ApplicationController
  def index
    @references = Reference.all
  end
```

After Google searching, every similar problem seems to be when upgrading from Rails 3 to Rails 4, or updating from OS to mavericks. My other controllers work so I feel it's safe to rule those out. I can't even get to the templates.

Comment: are you explicitly requiring this controller at some place ?

Comment: I don't think so. I have not placed a 'require references' anywhere if thats what you are talking about.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Rename this `ReferencesControllers`  to `ReferencesController`

Comment: Dang. Thank you vasuakeel. I'll mark it as answered in 10 minutes.

Comment: I don't get it.  What's the "circle" in the "circular dependency" here?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this when refactoring a Rails 4 app. `spring stop` fixed it.